# Is it possible using `ffmpeg.exe` in a shared hosting server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg

I use `ffmpeg.exe` to convert video files to `flv`but it does not work in a shared host.
Is it possible using `ffmpeg` in a shared host at all?
this is my code:

```
 private bool ReturnVideo(string fileName)
    {
        string html = string.Empty;
        //rename if file already exists

        int j = 0;
        string AppPath;
        string inputPath;
        string outputPath;
        string imgpath;
        AppPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
        //Get the application path
        inputPath = AppPath + "OriginalVideo";
        //Path of the original file
        outputPath = AppPath + "ConvertVideo";
        //Path of the converted file
        imgpath = AppPath + "Thumbs";
        //Path of the preview file
        string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/OriginalVideo/" + fileName);
        while (File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            j = j + 1;
            int dotPos = fileName.LastIndexOf(".");
            string namewithoutext = fileName.Substring(0, dotPos);
            string ext = fileName.Substring(dotPos + 1);
            fileName = namewithoutext + j + "." + ext;
            filepath = Server.MapPath("~/OriginalVideo/" + fileName);
        }
            this.fileuploadImageVideo.SaveAs(filepath);
        string outPutFile;
        outPutFile = "~/OriginalVideo/" + fileName;
        int i = this.fileuploadImageVideo.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        System.IO.FileInfo a = new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath(outPutFile));
        while (a.Exists == false)
        {

        }
        long b = a.Length;
        while (i != b)
        {

        }


        string cmd = " -i \"" + inputPath + "\\" + fileName + "\" \"" + outputPath + "\\" + fileName.Remove(fileName.IndexOf(".")) + ".flv" + "\"";
        ConvertNow(cmd);
        string imgargs = " -i \"" + outputPath + "\\" + fileName.Remove(fileName.IndexOf(".")) + ".flv" + "\" -f image2 -ss 1 -vframes 1 -s 280x200 -an \"" + imgpath + "\\" + fileName.Remove(fileName.IndexOf(".")) + ".jpg" + "\"";
        ConvertNow(imgargs);


        return true;
    }
    private void ConvertNow(string cmd)
    {
        string exepath;
        string AppPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
        //Get the application path
        exepath = AppPath + "ffmpeg.exe";
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = exepath;
        //Path of exe that will be executed, only for "filebuffer" it will be "flvtool2.exe"
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
        //The command which will be executed
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        proc.Start();

        while (proc.HasExited == false)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: It really shouldn't be possible, if only because it should violate several terms in your hosting agreement. You should not have access to the compute resources required to transcode. You should take a look at dedicated transcoding services such as [Amazon Elastic Transcode](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/?nc1=h_l2_as)

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: @Aron What do you know about his hosting agreement?

Comment: @brad i know that in a shared hosting environment, if everyone tried to run ffmpeg no one would have any fun. You are paying for hosting, a 100th share of a machine. Video encoding is an intensive task. If its allowed by the tc then the company would be quickly shafted.

Comment: If it is allowed it no longer shared hosting, and is now vps.

Comment: @Aron That's a generalization.  Obviously you're not wrong, but don't assume that all shared hosting is the same.  I have had two shared hosting providers in the past that made exceptions for some encoding work, provided I only did a single job at a time.  Sure, it helps that I referred a ton of customers to them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't instantiate a [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) object unless you're running at FullTrust.

> This class contains a link demand and an inheritance demand at the
>   class level that applies to all members. A SecurityException is thrown
>   when either the immediate caller or the derived class does not have
>   full-trust permission.

Usually hosting providers do not allow applications on shared hosts to run under Full Trust. Contact your support for more details or simply run your code on the server.

To change trust level, set in the web.config

```
<trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
```